# why is my navbaropen state not updating in the window addeventlistener (React js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, frontend

the condition is valid but for some reason the setNavbarOpen(false) is not working

here is the code:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const Navbar = () => {
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = useState(false);

  window.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    const navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar')
    if (!navbar.contains(e.target)) {
      setNavbarOpen(false)
      console.log('done')
    }
  })
  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <button
        className="toggle"
        onClick={() => setNavbarOpen((prev) => !prev)}
      >
        {navbarOpen ? 'close' : 'open'}
      </button>
      <ul className={`menu-nav${navbarOpen ? ' show-menu' : ''}`}>
        <li>change background</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};
export default Navbar;
```

I want to be able to close the navbar whenever i click anywhere on the screen but on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your click event listener is an unintentional side-effect. It is not created as part of the React component lifecycle.

Move it into a `useEffect` hook to instantiate the listener. Don't forget to return a cleanup function to remove the listener.

```js
const Navbar = () => {
  const [navbarOpen, setNavbarOpen] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const handler = (e) => {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
      if (!navbar.contains(e.target)) {
        setNavbarOpen(false);
        console.log("done");
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener("click", handler);
    () => {
      window.removeEventListener("click", handler);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <nav className="navbar">
      <p>Click outside me to toggle closed</p>
      <button className="toggle" onClick={() => setNavbarOpen((prev) => !prev)}>
        {navbarOpen ? "close" : "open"}
      </button>
      <ul className={`menu-nav ${navbarOpen ? "show-menu" : ""}`}>
        <li>change background</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Navbar />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```css
.navbar {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.menu-nav {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transition: all;
}

.show-menu {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```